# Changing function definition to point-free style

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pointfree

I'm having trouble writing this code that my professor has given me:

> Write a function called `digit7` which takes an `Int` and returns a `Bool` saying whether or not 7 is one of the digits. (Hint: use `show` to
>   turn the number into a list of characters.) Use `digit7` to create a
>   function of no parameters called `square7` which returns the smallest
>   number whose square contains a 7 as a digit.

The code that I have is:

```
digit7 l = elem '7' (show l)
```

This works but, I need the code written in a point-free style. I am also having trouble figuring out the `square7` function as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the `digit7` function, you can convert your definition to point-free style by using functional composition:

```
digit7 = (elem '7') . (show)
```

This is because:

```
   digit7 l
-> ((elem '7') . (show)) l     By substitution
-> (elem '7') ((show) l)       By definition of (.)
-> elem '7' (show l)           By operator precedence
```

---

As for the `square7` function, I recommend using `dropWhile` and `head`.

Comment: Of course, the parentheses here are unnecessary, and would probably be omitted in idiomatic Haskell, so the definition would just be `elem '7' . show`.

Comment: I agree. I wanted to make it 100% clear to the beginner what arguments the `.` operator is taking.

Comment: Valid, but it would have been better if you had simply explained the most basic rule: _infix operators ᴀʟᴡᴀʏꜱ have lower precedence than function application_.

Comment: Haskell gave me an error, i think it is a type error.

Comment: No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of ‘show’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      digit7 :: a0 -> Bool (bound at Hw#6.hs:1:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Either a b)

Comment: when i write it like this: digit7 l = (elem '7' . show)l it works fine. but when i delete the l's it gives me an error. I think the problem is with show since it wants some argument. Is there anyway we could replace show with another prelude function?

Comment: Writing it without the two `l` works fine for me. I was able to compile and run the code.

Comment: Debugging your type error is beyond my abilities. Can you open a new question, and post the **smallest piece of code** that can produce your error? Also include the error messages you get.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong with the code. Everything you've written was perfectly fine. i didn't write any type signatures since the “show” function is super-polymorphic and it won’t work right without you specifying the types.  all i had to write was digit7 :: Int -> Bool.